# One-to-many is returning empty array

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to solve a problem with the one-to-many relationship is not coming up when I query for it with both query builder and entity.

nest.js - 8.04
typeorm - 0.2.34

chapter.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Chapter, ChapterRepository])],
  controllers: [ChapterController],
  providers: [ChapterService]
})
export class ChapterModule {}
```

chapter.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Chapter {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
   
    @Column()
    transcript: string;

    @Column()
    translation: string;

    
    @ManyToOne(type => Book, book => book.chapter)
    book: Book;

    @OneToMany(type => Paragraph, paragraph => paragraph.chapter)
    paragraph: Paragraph[];

}
```

paragraph.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Paragraph, ParagraphRepository])],
  providers: [ParagraphService],
  controllers: [ParagraphController]
})
export class ParagraphModule {}
```

paragraph.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Paragraph {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type: 'mediumtext'})
    transcript: string;

    @Column({type: 'mediumtext'})
    translation: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Chapter , chapter => chapter.paragraph)
    chapter: Chapter;
   
}
```

chapter table

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | transcript | translation | bookId |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1  | "Hello"    | "Ola"       | 1      |
------------------------------------------
```

paragraph table

```
---------------------------------------------
| id | transcript | translation | chapterId |
|-------------------------------------------|
| 1  | "Hello"    | "Ola"       | 1         |
| 2  | "One"      | "Uno"       | 1         |
---------------------------------------------
```

chapter.service.ts

```
async getOneChapter(chapterId: number): Promise<Chapter> {
    
        try {
            return await this.chapterRepository.findOne({
                relations: ['paragraph'],
                where: {id: chapterId},
            })
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error)
        }
  
    }
```

result:

```
{
   id: 1,
   transcript: "hello",
   translation: "ola",
   paragraph: []
}
```

paragraph should have 2 objects instead of an empty array. I tried query builder and gets the same result

paragraph.repository.ts

```
async getOneChapter(chapterId: number): Promise<Chapter> {
        return this.createQueryBuilder('chapter')
                    .leftJoinAndSelect('chapter.paragraph', 'paragraph')
                    .where('chapter.id = :chapterId', {chapterId})
                    .getOne()
}
```